# Need to break a line after every span element I am using

Tags: html, css, styling

#### The context :

I am using span wrap with background images so I can have bullet point styling.

---

#### The problem :

If the content is too narrow, the next span element joins the same line.

Check the image below :

[image]

As you can see the span with content "VAT Rates and Refunds " joins the same line.

---

#### My code :

```css
.arrowIconFooter{
    background-image:url(../img/arrowFooter.png);
    background-position:left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 13px;   
    float: left;   
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#66809E; 
    font-weight:400;
}
```

```html
<section class="floating-left">
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">Cycle to Work Scheme Update</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">Divided Planning to Maximise Tax Credits</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">Maximum NI Contributions</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">VAT Rates and Refunds</span></a><br>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">February Question and Answer Section</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">February Key Tax Dates</span></a>
</section>
```

How can I make next following span next to go next line?

Comment: Youn can set the `<a>`or `<span>`to `display:block;`

Comment: I tried this didn't work

Comment: Additional remove the float: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35483222/676406

Comment: for the float, a clear:left would do the job too here ... depends what you expect and need to deal width ;) If it is to wrap links on its content, display:table will work as flot + clear here ...

Comment: Hi , Thanks it work with display:block

Comment: Why not use a list when it's indeed a list? What you do there mark-up-wise is quite ugly from a semantic point of view. It's very easy to achieve what you want with regular `<ul>` and `<li>`. http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/vertical05.htm

Comment: a list or nav tag instead section ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `display: block` and remove the `float` like this:

```css
.arrowIconFooter {
  display: block;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 23px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #66809E;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<section class="floating-left">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="arrowIconFooter">Cycle to Work Scheme Update</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="arrowIconFooter">Divided Planning to Maximise Tax Credits</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="arrowIconFooter">Maximum NI Contributions</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="arrowIconFooter">VAT Rates and Refunds</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="arrowIconFooter">February Question and Answer Section</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="arrowIconFooter">February Key Tax Dates</span>
  </a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add in your CSS class a :

```
clear:both
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `<a>` or `<span>` to `display:block;` and remove the `float`

**CSS**

```
.arrowIconFooter{
display: block;
background-image:url(../img/arrowFooter.png);
background-position:left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;    
padding: 6px 8px 6px 13px;     
font-family: monospace;
font-size:15px;
color:#66809E; 
font-weight:400;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/134/)**

Answer (score 0):

As you're including the spans inside an anchor tags and anchor tags are inline element so just style the anchor tags to display as block  "a {display : block}".

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to achieve the desired effect. Herebelow are just a some of them...

---

### Option 1 :

Replace your `float: left` with `display : inline-block` and `width : 100%` :

```css
.arrowIconFooter {
    background-image:url(../img/arrowFooter.png);
    background-position:left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 13px;   
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#66809E; 
    font-weight:400;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="floating-left">
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">Cycle to Work Scheme Update</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">Divided Planning to Maximise Tax Credits</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">Maximum NI Contributions</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">VAT Rates and Refunds</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">February Question and Answer Section</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">February Key Tax Dates</span></a>
</section>
```

---

### Option 2 :

Replace your `float: left` with `display : block` :

```css
.arrowIconFooter {
    background-image:url(../img/arrowFooter.png);
    background-position:left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 13px;   
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#66809E; 
    font-weight:400;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<section class="floating-left">
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">Cycle to Work Scheme Update</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">Divided Planning to Maximise Tax Credits</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">Maximum NI Contributions</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">VAT Rates and Refunds</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">February Question and Answer Section</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">February Key Tax Dates</span></a>
</section>
```

---

### Option 3 :

Add `clear : both` to your `a` elements :

```css
.arrowIconFooter {
    background-image:url(../img/arrowFooter.png);
    background-position:left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 13px;   
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#66809E; 
    font-weight:400;
    float: left;
    clear : both;
}
```

```html
<section class="floating-left">
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">Cycle to Work Scheme Update</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">Divided Planning to Maximise Tax Credits</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">Maximum NI Contributions</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">VAT Rates and Refunds</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">February Question and Answer Section</span></a>
  <a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">February Key Tax Dates</span></a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset block formating context of links to mind the float and break a line. here you may use `display:table;`(shrinks on content)  or `display:flex;`(use entire line).

---

> Maybe it is a good time to mind floats ? https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ (one link but many other in your search engine)
>
> ---

```css
.arrowIconFooter {
  background-image: url(../img/arrowFooter.png);
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 13px;
  float:left;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #66809E;
  font-weight: 400;
}

section a {
  display:table; /* wraps on content or  flex takes the whole line */
  }
```

```html
<section class="floating-left">
  <a href="#"> <span class="arrowIconFooter">Cycle to Work Scheme Update</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#"> <span class="arrowIconFooter">Divided Planning to Maximise Tax Credits</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#"> <span class="arrowIconFooter">Maximum NI Contributions</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#"> <span class="arrowIconFooter">VAT Rates and Refunds</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#"> <span class="arrowIconFooter">February Question and Answer Section</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#"> <span class="arrowIconFooter">February Key Tax Dates</span>
  </a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all of your links in a `<ul>` then wrap each link in a `<li>` and add `li { list-style: none; margin: 0 5px 10px; }` to CSS and remove the `float`.

**Snippet**

```css
.arrowIconFooter{
    background-image:url(http://iconshow.me/media/images/ui/ios7-icons/png/24/arrow-left-b.png);
    background-position:left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 20px;   
    /*float: left;*/   
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#66809E; 
    font-weight:400;
   
}
li { list-style: none; margin: 0 5px 10px; }
```

```html
<section>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">Cycle to Work Scheme Update</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">Divided Planning to Maximise Tax Credits</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">Maximum NI Contributions</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">VAT Rates and Refunds</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">February Question and Answer Section</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">  <span class="arrowIconFooter">February Key Tax Dates</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float:left; and use display:block;

```
.arrowIconFooter{
    display: block;
    background-image:url(../img/arrowFooter.png);
    background-position:left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 13px;      
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#66809E; 
    font-weight:400;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Some have suggested to turn `<span>` or `<a>` into block elements, however it's a bit more semantic to instead use line break tag, to start a new line `<br/>`.

If you don't want to do that, however, just use `<div>`s instead of spans. No point in putting spans just to restyle them as divs.

Comment: Inserting `br` elements for styling purposes is NOT semantic.